# variable updated by redux state does not trigger useEffect

Tags: reactjs, redux

variable updated by redux state does not trigger useEffect

not sure what i am missing but i can see state.user.fen updating but it does not trigger useEffect to be called?

```
export default function BoardSquare({ piece, black, position,isFromSquare,isToSquare}) {

           dispatch(setFen(fen))
}
```

//userActions.js

```
    export const setFen = (fen) => (dispatch) => {
       
        dispatch({ 
            type: SET_FEN,
            payload: fen,
        });
    }
```

//userReducer.js

```
export default function userReducer(state = initialState,action) {


    switch(action.type){


        case  SET_FEN: 
        return{
            ...state,
            fen: action.payload
        }
        
}
```

```
function GameApp() {

const fen = useSelector(state => state.user.fen) 

useEffect(() => { 
alert("should be working now ?")
console.log("should be working now ??????")
setBoard(fen)
}, [fen])

}
```

Comment: please post how did modify the state of fen and structure of the user.fen object, put console.log in component

Comment: Oleg 
const fen = useSelector(state => state.user.fen)  is the variable I expect to be updated ? and i've added more info on how I update the store

Comment: function GameApp() {  const fen = useSelector(state => state.user.fen) ; console.log(fen);.....}